# Use of OGNL expression to access request headers in Tiles 2

Tags: tiles, ognl

I'm using Tiles 2.2.2  in my application (Struts 2.2.3). I want to use expressions in order to modify my screen composition depending on some attribute in the request. Basically, I would like to change the extends of a screen depending if there is a header in the request with name "x-requested-with" and the value is "XMLHttpRequest". Is it possible to do that? I've tried to do a simple example with an attribute:

```
<put-attribute name="test"   expression="OGNL:requestScope"  cascade="true"/>
```

I've tried different expressions like OGNL:%{#request.headers.referer}, OGNL:#request.headers.referer, OGNL:requestScope.headers.referer , etc. But it always returns null. I haven't found any documentation on how the OGNL expressions works on Tiles, so I'm working based on how I would do it with Struts. But it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you initializing Tiles? If you're using the StrutsTilesListener, OGNL expressions in tiles.xml won't be evaluated.

In my Struts2 app, I am using the org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener in web.xml and OGNL evaluation is working:

```
<listener>
      <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In my case, I have a custom TilesResult with a property called 'content':

```
<put-attribute name="content" expression="OGNL:content" />
```

Comment: Humm, I have to try that. You mention you have a custom TilesResult. Why don't you use the one provided by the Struts2-Tiles plugin?

Comment: I extend the provided org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult and add some custom properties to be set via an Action's @Result annotation parameters.